# How do you insert/append a react Component on mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Like the title says, on mount I want to insert/append a Component, either as a child or sibling.

Things I've found online that haven't worked:

- `ReactDOM.render()`

  - This replaces the whole node and its children with the `<Component />`.
- `.insertAdjacentElement()`

  - I get the type error `Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.`
- `.appendChild()`

  - I get the error `Argument of type 'JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.`
- `.append()`

  - I get error `Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Node'.`

For example:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Code that makes <Component /> appear in DOM
}, []);

<div>
  <div>
    <p>Something</p>
    {/* On mount <Component /> is inserted here */}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Edited for more detail]:

I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to enter anything inside of the `return ();`.

All functionality to insert the `<Component />` needs to be done above that.

Comment: You may be able to do this by creating the component via `useState<React.FC>(null)` and setting the component within your initial `useEffect`. But if you know you want the component to be rendered onMount why not just directly use the component instead of making it conditional? Do you intend to conditionally remove it, or are you just hoping to adjust the timing of component rendering?

Comment: Just render the component then. If you want to toggle some appearance of the component, toggle a class via state + useEffect (e.g. fade in transition).

Comment: The reason why I can't just use the component is because I'm developing a hook. So when the user uses the hook within the file, it will automatically append my component to the DOM for the user. That's also why I need to insert it from inside a useEffect etc

Comment: Make your hook return a component, and whatever else.  Don't access the DOM directly..

Answer (score 1):

You could handle it like this:

1. use a **state** boolean flag to handle the component's visibility
2. in the **JSX** part return the dynamic content(*which is also a react component*), with a **condition**
3. use an **useEffect** hook to execute a scope just once after the first render, to change the visibility to true
4. create a clickHandler that **switches** the visibility `on/off`, and link it to a button

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const DynamicContent = () => <div>dynamic content</div>;

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(false);        //1

  useEffect(() => {
    setVisibility(true);                                     //3
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisibility(!isVisible);                               //4
  };

  return (
    <div className="my-component">
      <h1 className="my-component__dynamic-content">This is dynamic content</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>change visibility</button>
      {isVisible && <DynamicContent />}                      //2
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

note that I am using:

- AtomicDesign folder structure
- BEM className pattern

Answer (score 0):

Most of the methods listed are DOM api calls (`insertAdjacentElement`, `appendChild()` etc.) The reason you're getting all these type errors is because you can't mix and match React and DOM elements like that. React uses it's own virtual dom and doing something outside it's rendering mechanisms is a huge anti-pattern.

`<Component />` although this looks like a DOM element, JSX actually compiles to [function calls](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQHgJglgbgfAUMRpKwUxIAOMDKB7AWwFMAXACwgDsBzEAemzXQG8BjQzPSoykgZwB0BAIaYAFGPYFO3XgEpgAXhjApMniTkBfJqDop4GfdBhA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&modules=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.22.9&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D) behind the scenes. You could potentially do something like this to render HTML directly in your effect.

```
const textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
node.appendChild(textnode);
```

But this will not be treated as React and you'll lose the state management functionality. The proper way to do this is to use a conditional in your `render()` method like the other answers suggested.